# googlechartのColumnChartの色を一つだけ変えたい

Tags: javascript

googlechartのColumnChartの色を一つだけ変えたいのですが、実装の仕方を教えてください。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 現状どうやってグラフを描いているかくらい載せていただかないと回答し辛いと思います

Comment: [ガイド](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) の中に色の設定についての例があります。要するにデータの作成（あるいは加工）時に色指定すればいいかと思います。(作成されたSVGを直接いじるようなのは愚策かと）